# Download with Url change

Tags: c#, .net

I encountered a situation like this

**Problem**:  I go to a website to view a file and the website has something to show a document by Iframe.
(Note: Whenever I go to that website , I get a **new link**)

**Idea**:  I decided to make a program to get this file by the following

- First I go to the website by using a httpwebrequest to get "**new link**"
- After that I use Webclient to download file with "**new link**".

But it's not working, because when I go to the source to get link, it loads an  **Iframe** and this website does not allow me to go and download it anymore...

I need a way to get new link "**without active Iframe**" and after that I can download it

Can anyone help me?

Comment: We can't really help without seeing *anything* about the requests/responses being made and the code making them.  The principle is always the same... Make an HTTP request, read its response.  If there's a value you need from that response to make another request, parse out the value and make the subsequent request with it.  Whether or not there happens to be an `iframe` makes no difference.  It's still just an HTTP request/response.

Comment: Hint: [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) is your best friend ;-)